# How to copy same object to two variable without mutating each other in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

What I am trying to do is copying a object to two states using spread operator but when I am changing one of them, other on is also changing.

Actually I am implementing an edit operation for this ***itemDetails***, which is fetched when mounted and have multiple items inside an array. ***editItemIndex*** is passed when edit modal for that item is open. After edit item is replaced.

I am trying to copy a duplicate of itemDetails for reset as ***oItemDetails*** but the items of ***oItemDetails*** are also changed after edit.

*please provide me some suggestions for avoiding copy by reference*

```
state: {
    itemDetails: [],
    oItemDetails: [],
    editItem: [],
    editItemIndex: null,
},
actions: {
    async showItemsEditModal ({state, commit}, value) {
      commit('setItemsModalStatus', true);
      state.oItemDetails = await {...value};
      state.itemDetails = await {...value};
    },
    async openEditItemModal ({state, commit}, data) {
      state.editItem = await {...data.data}
      state.editItemIndex = await data.item_index
   },
   async editItem ({state, commit}, data) {
      state.itemDetails.items[state.editItemIndex] = await data
   },
   async resetItem ({state}) {
      console.log(state.itemDetails, state.oItemDetails)
      state.itemDetails = await {...state.oItemDetails}
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very confusing. You reference `state.editItem` and `state.editItemIndex`, but those are not in your state object?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` does not copy observers.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards i have a very long file, i have given this code to make the context

Comment: try this library https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction

Answer (score 3):

You need deep clone to avoid [copy reference](https://www.codementor.io/ramnmiklus/deep-copying-an-object-in-javascript-mdlj2c318) of deep object, use `lodash clone deep` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))` instead `{...value}`.

Note that the performance of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` isn't good, [lodash clone deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

To clone an object you need to spread and **store it in a variable** and use the clone, now you pass a spread as an argument instead of cloning it and passing the clone.

Below a generic example of cloning:

Notice that the clone does not change after the original object is updated.

```js
const exampleObject = {
  title: "Crystal Silence",
  artist: "Chick Corea"
}

// Clone the object

const clone = {...exampleObject};

// NOTE: JSON.stringify is used for display purposes only

let display = "";
display = "Example Object before: " + JSON.stringify(exampleObject) +  "<br/>";
display += "Clone before: " + JSON.stringify(clone) +  "<br/>";

// Now change the exampleObject by adding a new attribute

exampleObject.album = "Return to Forever";

// And check what happens to the clone:

display += "Example Object after: " + JSON.stringify(exampleObject) + "<br/>" ;
display += "Clone after: " + JSON.stringify(clone);

const main = document.getElementById("main");
main.innerHTML = display;
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```